# Not getting FCM message in foreground ios app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm registering and initiating firebase in ios like this in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    FIRApp.configure()
```

And then setting the callback like this in AppDelegate

```
 func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("fir msg front : \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

    print("fir msg : \(userInfo)")
}
```

When I send a message from my server,when the app is not in foreground, it shows a notification, but when the app is in foreground, I don't see any notification and also none of the callback is getting called. Am I missing something?

Comment: In which iOS version you are facing this issue? Have you implemented UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate?

Comment: im testing in 10.3.3 and have not implemented UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate.

Comment: i followed this documentation 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate methods. From iOS 10 you will get callback in UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate methods.

```
// The method will be called on the delegate only if the application is in the foreground. If the method is not implemented or the handler is not called in a timely manner then the notification will not be presented. The application can choose to have the notification presented as a sound, badge, alert and/or in the notification list. This decision should be based on whether the information in the notification is otherwise visible to the user.

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions){

}

// The method will be called on the delegate when the user responded to the notification by opening the application, dismissing the notification or choosing a UNNotificationAction.

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (){

}
```

Without implementing these you were getting error in the following line-

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

Comment: Thanks,It worked.Its a pity that google doesn't include this in firebase documentation clearly.